# Contravariant components $a^k$ of the acceleration $\boldsymbol{a}$ of a particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration, tensor-calculus, coordinate-systems

Well I was studying the uses of Christoffel in physics and I got the following Idea :

Let us consider a particle moving on a trajectory defined by spherical coordinates $r, \theta, \varphi$, the acceleration $\boldsymbol{a}$ is a vector of course, if we wanted to determinate its contravariant components $a^k$. let the trajectory be defined by: $r=c,\ \theta=\omega t \ , \varphi= \pi/4 \ , t \ \text{is time}$.

Well to do this we need to determinate the Christoffel symbols, for this trajectory:
$$\Gamma_{1 \ 3}^3=1/r \ ; \ \Gamma_{2 \ 3}^3=\text{cotan} \ \theta \ ; \ \Gamma_{3 \ 3}^3=0$$

My questions :

1. How can we identify the contravariant components of this particle ?
2. Can we just treat this particle as a point $M$ and determinate the contravariant components of $\frac{\partial^2 \boldsymbol{OM}}{\partial t^2}$ ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why don't you start from your identities ? $\Gamma_{2 \ 1}^2=1/c \ ; \Gamma_{3 \ 2}^3=\text{cotan}(\omega . t) \ ; \Gamma_{2 \ 2}^1=-c \ ; \Gamma_{3 \ 3}^1=-c \text{sin}^2(\omega . t) \ ; \Gamma{3 \  3}^2=-\text{-sin}(\omega . t) \text{cos}(\omega .t)$

Comment: You mean $\Gamma_{3 \ 3}^2=-\text{sin}(\omega . t) \text{cos}(\omega . t)$

Comment: Yes, Why don't you start from using them ?

Comment: If the coordinate system is orthonormal - which appears to be the case - then contravariant components are equal to the covariant components in $R^3$.

Comment: Are you fine to start a full proof from $\boldsymbol{OM}=r\ \text{sin}\ \theta \ \text{cos}\ \varphi \ \boldsymbol{e_1^0}+r\ \text{sin}\ \theta \ \text{sin}\ \varphi \ \boldsymbol{e_2^0}+r\ \text{cos}\ \theta \ \boldsymbol{e_3^0}$

Comment: @CinaedSimson I think the coordinate system is curvilinear !

Comment: @MohamedELF Well that was my question !

Comment: Okay, write down your metric, calculate the inverse, then use the metrics to raise and lower indices as needed. IMHO, the $R^3$ analogy with general relativity would be the Frenet Frame where the fields are written in terms of derviatives of the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve this problem and here's my attempts :

> Quick recall :
>   $$\begin{align}
> \\ \mathbf{e_1} &= \partial_1 \mathbf{M}=\sin  \theta \cos  \varphi \mathbf{i}+\sin \theta \sin \varphi \mathbf{j}+ \cos \theta \mathbf{k}
> \\ \mathbf{e_2}&= \partial_2 \mathbf{M}=r\cos\theta\cos \varphi\mathbf{i}+r\cos\theta \sin\varphi\mathbf{j}-r\sin \theta \mathbf{k} 
> \\ \mathbf{e_3}&=\partial_3 \mathbf{M}=-r\sin\theta\sin \varphi \mathbf{i}+r\sin\theta\cos\varphi \mathbf{j} \end{align}$$

Well I had the same idea as yours which is let consider this particle to be a point let's call it $\mathbf{M}$ and we're going to determinate the components of $\mathbf{a}$ to do this we need the to determinate the Christoffel symbols values as @Gunter said :

**Differentials of natural base vectors :**

$\mathbf{i, j, k}$ are constants in their modules and directions, the differential of $\mathbf{e_1}$ is :
$$d\mathbf{e_1}=(\cos\theta\cos \varphi \mathbf{i}+\cos\theta\sin\varphi \mathbf{j})d\theta+(-\sin\theta \sin\varphi\mathbf{i}+\sin\theta\cos\varphi)d\varphi $$
We notice that the terms inside the brackets are respectively $\mathbf{e_2}/r$ and $\mathbf{e_3}/r$, thus:
$$d\mathbf{e_1}=\frac{d\theta}r \mathbf{e_2}+\frac{d\varphi}r \mathbf{e_3}$$
With differentiation also we get:
$$\begin{align}
d\mathbf{e_2}&=(-rd\theta)\mathbf{e_1}+(dr/r)\mathbf{e_2}+(\text{cotan}\ \theta d\varphi)\mathbf{e_3} \\
d\mathbf{e_3}&=(-r\sin^2 \theta d\varphi)\mathbf{e_1}+(-\sin\theta \cos \theta d\varphi)\mathbf{e_2}+((dr/r)+\text{cotan } \ \theta d\theta)\mathbf{e_3}
\end{align}$$
I'm still far from the answer but we concluded a really interesting :
$$d\mathbf{e_i}=a_i^k \mathbf{e_k} \qquad(1)$$
Where $a_i^k$ the contravariant components of $d\mathbf{e_i}$:
Let's start solving the problem :

Note the spherical coordinates : $u^1=r, \ u^2=\theta, \ u^3=\varphi$
So :   $du^1=dr, \ du^2=d\theta, \ du^3=d\varphi$ and the components can be written as :
$$a_i^j=\Gamma_{ki}^i du^k \qquad (2)$$

In $(1)$ we notice that the components $a_i^k$ are linear combination for example :
$$a_1^2=d\theta/r , \ a_3^3=(dr/r)+\text{cotan} \ \theta d\theta$$
In $(2)$ we have the quantities $\Gamma_{ki}^j$ are functions of $r,\theta, \varphi$ and we obtain simply by identifying $a_i^j$ for example :
 $$a_3^3=(dr/r)+\text{cotan} \ \theta d\theta=\Gamma_{1 \ 3}^3du^1+\Gamma_{2 \ 3}^3du^2+\Gamma_{3 \ 3}^3 du^3$$
Thus :
$$\Gamma_{1 \ 3}^3=1/r, \ \Gamma_{2 \ 3}^3=\text{cotan} \ \theta,\ \Gamma_{3 \ 3}^3=0$$ 
And here you go you have the identities and for the $\mathbf{a}$ components are :
$$\fbox{$a^1=\frac{d^2 u^1}{dt^2}+\Gamma_{ik}^1 \frac{du^i}{dt} \frac{du^k}{dt}, \ a^2=0, \ a^3=0$}$$
Hope it helps go trough these final results and you will solve your problem, but don't hurry, first of all determinate the values of Christoffel symbols at the trajectory with the system you gave. Good luck !

Comment: Thank you I thought that using them won't gave a result but thanks for showing it to me !!

Comment: You are welcome !